# There are no Content-Length header in response from GitHub API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, github-api

I'm working on Web client for GitHub. I fetch data from [api.github.com](https://api.github.com/)  using `native JS` and `XMLHttpRequest()`. I have an idea to make progress bar to indicate AJAX response status. But I have a problem: there are no Content-Length header in response and it's impossible to count loaded data percent.

But when I am sending requests via curl, Content-Length header is available.

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues\?page\=1\&per_page\=3

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 11:28:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8808
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 54
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1459945275
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
...
```

AJAX Request function:

```
var ajaxRequest = function(user, repo) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var pag = '?page=' + page + '&per_page=' + count;

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            clearIssues();
            addIssues(response);
        }
    };

    xhttp.onprogress = function(event) {
        progress_bar.innerHTML = event.loaded + ' loaded';
    };

    xhttp.open('GET', api_url + 'repos/' + user + '/' + repo + '/issues' + pag, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/vnd.github.v3+json');
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhttp.send();
};
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: This appears to be a CORS issue. When I try that URL, the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header does not include `Content-Length`. Since that is coming from the server, I don't think you have any control over it. Maybe see if you can get any support from github.

Comment: I've got feedback from GitHub support:
There's no Content-Length header because of this (you will see that header in the response from the API when you make a request from the browser):

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

You can read more about chunked transfer here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

And you will see the same behavior in curl if you do this (there won't be a Content-Length header):

curl -v https://api.github.com/repos/atom/atom/issues -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -o /dev/null